# Extract object and save it as an image.png using c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Actually I work on a car detection project at real time, when I launch the camera I want to make a screenshot (.png) for any car and save it in a path, which means i need a function in opencv that does the screenshot of just a car detected (not all windows).

Suppose you have the following image:

[image: Cars on the street]

Now i want to extract to individual images each of the independent cars, like this for example:

[image: Detected car]

And save in  path/image_date.png.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on your own, and (2) learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. Please provide a [mre] to your _specific_ problem. What have you tried so far? Please show any relevant code.

Comment: If you are already using opencv on your project, you can simply save your photo using "imwrite" function

Answer (score 2):

Given an image and a bounding box that is determined by your car detector:

```
cv::Mat image = …;
cv::Rect roi = …; // roi stands for "region of interest"
cv::Mat output = image(roi); // slice the car rectangle out of the image
cv::imwrite("car.png", output);
```

Note that this `operator()` will reference the original image data, no data copy will be made. So this is a very efficient way of working on a specific region of interest.

How to best detect the cars in an image in the first place, is too broad for a SO question.

Comment: thanks for your reply , could you please send me a code example about that?

Comment: This is a code example.

Comment: yes sir , please give me 5 min ,how can i  integrate this function in this code : https://github.com/JdeRobot/traffic-monitor/blob/master/src/main.cpp